# Sql lock tables many server one database

Tags: mysql, multiprocessing, locking

I have a database (mysql-ubuntu) from which I access from different process on many servers.

I would that this process access a specific table one at time.

I cant manage this race condition from local because there are many server so i think that mysql can do that for me.

I try with this:

```
mysql -se "LOCK TABLES account WRITE; SELECT * FROM account WHERE in_uso = '0' LIMIT 1; UNLOCK TABLES;"
```

but apparently it doesn't work: the process ignore the lock and proceed with the query even if the lock is taken from another process. I think the problem is about session...

How can I manage this situation?

Comment: The way you describe it, it should not happen. The most likely reason for that is that your description isn't exact enough. Can you be a bit more specific? E.g. what exactly did oyu do to lock the table from the other mentioned process (as it is most likely not locked, but we currently have to guess what you did there). Maybe something like: *my create table statement is: ... my tests: on client 1, i open mysql client, do "lock tables account write;" and let the session open. on client 2, i open mysql client, enter "above code", and i get a result. I verified that session 1 is still active.*

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to acquire a WRITE lock just to read one row from a table. This is a BAD idea and will cripple your concurrency since it will block all other processes from accessing the table.  Have the other processes use transactions, or if they already do then just read from the table without trying to lock it